# Comparing character strings in R

Tags: r, comparison, character

I am new to R programming. I have a set of characters stored in variables `x1` to `x25` for instance `x1` has values `"v21", "v345", "v212"` etc `x2 to x25`  contain character values of similar variations e.g. `"v45", "v67", "v556", "v21", "v44"` and they `(x1 to x25)` are all of different lengths. These were like results from an analysis.
I want to write a function that would compare the character values of `x1 to x25` and output the results of characters that appeared FIVE times or more in the values `x1 to x25`. So for instance I would like to see a result like:

```
"v21", "v67", "v556", "v45", "v44", "v212"
```

if these were the characters that appeared `x1 to x25`. I have been doing visual inspection and writing down the results but it's taking too much time of which I am constrained of.

If this is possible (which I know is), can someone help me out please so I can also learn from it.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  have you found the function `table`? and the `apply` family?  Please share a bit of the code you have tried and where it has failed.  Also, if you can include a bit of your data it will help get a better answer, `dput(head(yourdata, 20))`.

Answer (score 3):

First, an example setup:

```
x1 <- c("v21", "v67", "v556", "v45", "v44", "v212")
x2 <- c("v21", "v67", "v556", "v45", "v44", "v212")
x3 <- c("v21", "v67", "v556", "v45", "v44", "v212")
x4 <- c("v21", "v67", "v556", "v45", "v44", "v212")
x5 <- c("v22", "v61", "v56", "v3", "v4", "v20")
x6 <- c("v22", "v61", "v56", "v3", "v4", "v20")
x7 <- c("v22", "v61", "v56", "v3", "v4", "v20")
x8 <- c("v22", "v61", "v56", "v3", "v4", "v20")
x9 <- c("v22", "v61", "v56", "v3", "v4", "v20")
x10 <- c("v556")
x11 <- c("v12","v345","v55")
x12 <- c("v12","v345","v55")
x13 <- c("v12","v345","v55")
x14 <- c("v12","v345","v55")
x15 <- c("v1", "v51", "v43", "v43")
x16 <- c("v1", "v51", "v43", "v43")
x17 <- c("v1", "v51", "v43", "v43")
x18 <- c("v1", "v51", "v43", "v43")
x19 <- c("v200")
x20 <- c("v200")
x21 <- c("v200")
x22 <- c("v39","v556","v41")
x23 <- c("v39","v556","v41")
x24 <- c("v39","v556","v41")
x25 <- c("v39","v556","v41")
```

Having 25 variables stored separately can make it difficult to work with them all. To get them all together use

```
vars <- paste0("x",1:25)
corpus <- mget(vars)
```

Then `corpus` is a list containing all of your data. To find what you want--all the "v###" that occur at least 5 times--create a table and then perform a boolean test on each element. Extract the names of those values to get the "v###".

```
valTable <- table(unlist(corpus))
keepers <- names(valTable[valTable >= 5])
keepers
# [1] "v20"  "v22"  "v3"   "v4"   "v43"  "v556" "v56"  "v61"
```

Comment: +1 for going to the effort of making example data on the OPs behalf. You shouldn't have to!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer assuming your x's are in a list. If not first make one:

```
my.vars <- list(x1, x2, ..., x25)

corpus <- unique(unlist(my.vars))
occurences <- sapply(X=corpus,
                     FUN=function (k) {
                       occurences <- sapply(my.vars, function (l) k %in% l)
                       occurences <- sum(occurences)
                     })
names(occurences) <- corpus

i.want <- occurences[occurences >= 5]
```